# Kia Sportage 2017 seat belts alarm

Tags: kia, seat-belt

My Kia Sportage started to do strange things. After someone, who occupies the passenger seat unleashes the seatbelt before the car stops, my car starts beeping annoyingly even when passenger is not in a car anymore. An only complete restart helps.
Is that a some software glitch, or something mechanical?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!